# Upload a File To An SSH Folder

Tags: ssh, sftp, file-transfer

I'm trying to connect to my SSH to send a file for it using WinSCP, but when I try to connect what I got is this:

[image: WinSCP Error]

Remember that I'm using **tcsh** as my default shell, and I can't change it.

What I can do?

Comment: Have you tried a "standard" scp file transfer from the command line? Give that a try or alternatively, try WinSCP instead of filezilla.

Comment: Of course. I've configured Ruby on Rails there before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp), or [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) if you are on Windows.

Comment: Hrm, sounds awfully familiar.

Comment: Sorry Erik, didn't see your reference to winSCP. Guess it helps to read the entire comment... :D I did go the distance and add the links, though.